# SSDL Content of the edmx file emptied after update from database

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 (SP1) with EF.
When I tried to update the edmx file of my application, the SSDL Content part of the file gets emptied.
Consequences are that the mapping details of every entity is emptied, meaning tables that already exist don't refresh.

For example, the SSDL Content section looked like this before :

```
<!-- SSDL content -->
<edmx:StorageModels>
<Schema Namespace="DataAccess.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2005" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
    <EntityContainer Name="DataAccessStoreContainer">
      <EntitySet Name="Amdec" EntityType="DataAccess.Store.Amdec" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
...
```

After, I got that :

```
<!-- SSDL content -->
<edmx:StorageModels>
<Schema Namespace="DataAccess.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2005" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
    **<EntityContainer Name="DataAccessStoreContainer"/>**
```

Any clue ?

Comment: Where did the original SSDL come from? I believe that if you update your model from the database it will basically replace existing SSDL with a new one generated based on the database schema.

Comment: The original was generated by another developer. We are 4 working on the same project, using TFS and connecting to the very same database.
I'm the only one with that problem...

Comment: Looks like you are connecting to a different database that has no tables other people have. This may also be a permission problem when you connect to the correct database but you don't have permissions to see some/all tables and therefore EF "thinks" you don't have any tables and wipes your SSDL as it sees the database differently than for other developers on your team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Pawel, 
I used integrated security on the edmx connection string since I can access the server but I have no rights on the database itself. 
I replaced it with SQL connection credential and it works fine now.